# How can I do a multidimensional lookup table in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

New to Objective-C here...

I have a unique string code as the key that I'd like to use to look up associated values.

It seems an NSDictionary is what I'm looking for but I believe this is only used to lookup one value for a given key.

Can anyone provide the code on how to declare/fill a multidimensional immutable NSDictionary? Also the code to retrieve the values?

Also, please let me know I'm going about this the wrong way

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: example of array within a dictionary .... using example data from your comment.

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *firstSet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:43, 22];
NSArray *secondSet = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:32, 50];

[myDictionary setValue:firstSet forKey:@"010"];
[myDictionary setValue:secondSet forKey:@"011"];

// Get a value out - should be the 50 that you want
NSInteger *myValue = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"011"] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Not tested - but should be 95% right.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.  Are you able to provide with actual values?  i.e. if the format is [uniquecode, percentage1, percentage2] and entry one is [010, 43, 22], entry two is [011, 32, 50]?   And then show how I can get the 50 from the second entry?   If this is asking too much I understand

Comment: My example embeds a dictionary within a dictionary, so you need two keys to get at 50 - that's my attempt to answer your 'multidimensional dictionary'.  Now you've explained your problem a bit more, I have a question.  You can do your example as an array stored in a dictionary.  I'll try to reword the example.

Comment: @sayguh - I've updated the example.  If you're worried about this taking too much time - don't worry, but don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helps you.  THis is how people 'reward' others for help here, and if you don't do it then people will notice and stop answering questions.  Glad to help.

Comment: Getting a few errors. Is that because you are storing primitive INTs instead of NSInteger objects?  Also, do I need to release those NSArrays or are they autoreleased?  Thanks!

Comment: Errors due to int vs NSInteger - possibly - you'd need to tell me the error and the line.  As I said - untested code.  As for releasing - you ned to release everything that has had alloc called on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make any object you want be the value for a given key in an `NSDictionary`. This includes `NSArray` or even another `NSDictionary`. Using either of these would allow you to associate multiple values with one key.

Comment: Yea, I thought so I just can't seem to find a good code sample for this.   Anyway you could provide one?

Answer (score 1):

For nested `NSDictionaries` or custom KVC-complient classes you can use [`keyPaths`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html), and for nested `NSArrays` [`indexPaths`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/IndexPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010167-SW1).

Also stackoverflow will give you many examples.